# How to select dropdown option1 and do search untill the last optionn, once page is reloaded,next time loop fails,to find the dropdown option

Tags: python, linux, selenium

1)I wanted to select drop down option1 and do search(click),and come back to previous page select next option2 from drop down and do search(click), I wanted to do the same untill the last drop down list.

2) I tried with for loop, its working for first option1, loop can select the option1 from drop down and do search(click), next time loop is not finding the drop down option.

3)Can you please help to solve the problem?

```
driver.find_element_by_id("seller_inventory_add_product_onebyone_inputSearchProduct").send_keys("Mobile")
driver.find_element_by_id("inventory_obosearch_go_item_search").click()#next button
print "next button clicled"
selement = driver.find_element_by_id("seller_inventory_add_product_onebyone_selectProductGroupName")
all_optionss = selement.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
time.sleep(2)
i=0
for j in all_optionss:
        print "test the loop"  
        selement = driver.find_element_by_id("seller_inventory_add_product_onebyone_selectProductGroupName")
        all_optionss = selement.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
        time.sleep(3)
        if (i < 24):
            print "2nd time loop"
            time.sleep(2)
            j.click()
            print j.text
            time.sleep(4)
            print "before passing value"
            var4 = driver.find_element_by_id("seller_inventory_add_product_onebyone_inputSearchProduct")
            print "before sending value"
            time.sleep(4)
            var4.clear()
            time.sleep(4)
            var4.send_keys(j.text) 
            time.sleep(4)   
            print "after sending values"
            driver.find_element_by_id("inventory_inputSearchProduct_go").click()#next button
            print "next button clicled"
            time.sleep(4)  
            selement = driver.find_element_by_id("seller_inventory_add_product_onebyone_selectProductGroupName").click
            print "finding the options"
        else:

            break
```

Answer (score 0):

does it open in a new page/tab? if not, you can back to the page by the previous button

```
driver.execute_script("window.history.go(**x**)")
```

where x = number of page/s, eg. if you need to go back 2 pages, value should be **-2**

Comment: I used above command but it is not working again the same error. I think after click page is reloaded, so next time it not possible to find the next option from dropdwon. I am getting below error.

Comment: j.click()
 ge, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <option> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

Comment: possible to edit the the question with the url so we could check? 
1. either the page has been refreshed, 
2. directed to wrong site or 
3. the element did not appear. if there is no changes in the code above and inserted only the driver.execute_script, there should be a wait option before going to the element

Comment: 1)Yes, page is refreshed once search button is clicked,2) I print the current url it is the same page, it is not going to wrong page. 3)I used wait option still, the same exception.[stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document]. any other option is there to solve the issue